# The via USB connected SCSI (UAS)-device for mass storage cannot be stopped

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, usb, ssd

Since I bought a SSD Case, I am not being able to unplug my SSD. When I want to safely remove the ssd from my computer, windows just says:

Original in Dutch: `"Kan apparaat Via USB aangesloten SCSI (UAS)-apparaat voor massaopslag niet stoppen"`

Translated in English: `"The via USB connected SCSI (UAS)-device for mass storage cannot be stopped."`

How can I fix this? I am constantly running the command `chkdsk /f` to move my SSD, but that is REALLY bad for my SSD. It caused my SSD to damage all files, so I don't want that to be happening again.

I tried searching with the search term in English and Dutch, but I could just not find the solution.

PC Specs in case it is required:

```
OS: Windows 10 Pro
Processor: I5 4690
Videocard: Sapphire R9 380 Nitro Edition
Memory: 16GB (2 x 8GB) HyperX Fury Blu
Motherboard: Gigabyte Z97-D3H
Storage: 1TB WD Blue, 256GB Samsung 850 Evo, the SSD whom is in the case: 120GB Samsung 840 Evo
```

[My Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGRG8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of Salihcan Taşarkuyu didn't quitte fix it, but it gave me some clues at least.

In order to unplug it safely, you have to remove every registry value that leads to an address on the SSD, so for example a reference to a shortcut I had. You can do this by downloading CCleaner or any registry cleaning program.

Answer (score 2):

There could be a program clinging to the SSD. Open Resource Monitor(resmon), go to the Disk tab, try to find what's using SSD.

Comment: Great, it worked!